# ASP, vbscript, CDO Email through AWS is truncated?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, vbscript, asp-classic

I am moving this classic ASP app to AWS and using AWS SES SMTP to send site emails (automated, post registration email).

So, the code below works but when the email arrives it is truncated (incomplete)?

**Mail Function:**

```html
Function Sendmail(Sender, Subject, Recipient, Body)
 dim myMail, strServer
 strServer = Request.ServerVariables("server_name")
 if strServer <> "localhost" then
   Set myMail=Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
   myMail.Subject=Subject
   myMail.From=Sender
   myMail.To=Recipient
   myMail.HTMLBody=Body
   myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
   'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
   myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
   'Server port
   myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=465
   'requires authentication
   myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate")=1
   'username
   myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")="a username"
   'password
   myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")="a password"
   'startTLS
   myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")=true      
   myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
   myMail.Send
   set myMail=nothing
 end if 
End function
```

**Mail Body**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'><html lang='en'><head> <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1258'> <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'> <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'> <meta name='format-detection' content='telephone=no'> <title>Title</title> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.website.com/styles.css'> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.website.com/responsive.css'></head><body style='margin:0; padding:0;' bgcolor='#F0F0F0' leftmargin='0' topmargin='0' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0'><table border='0' width='100%' height='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' bgcolor='#F0F0F0'><tr><td align='center' valign='top' bgcolor='#F0F0F0' style='background-color: #F0F0F0;'> <br/> <table border='0' width='600' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='container'><tr><td class='header' align='left'><img src='http://www.website.com/images/email/logo_small_en.png'/> </td></tr><tr> <td class='container-padding content' align='left' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'> <br/><div class='title'>Welcome to the site! </div><br/><div class='body-text'> <p>Welcome to the website<div class='hr'></div><br/><div class='subtitle'>Have fun!</div><br/> </td></tr><tr> <td class='container-padding footer-text' align='left'><br/>&copy; 2016 <br/> <br/>You are receiving this email because you registered for the website. Please click here to <a href=''>unsubscribe</a>. <br/> </td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

**Truncated always at the same spot?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'><html lang='en'><head> <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1258'> <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'> <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'> <meta name='format-detection' content='telephone=no'> <title>Title</title> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.website.com/styles.css'> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.website.com/responsive.css'></head><body style='margin:0; padding:0;' bgcolor='#F0F0F0' leftmargin='0' topmargin='0' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0'><table border='0' width='100%' height='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' bgcolor='#F0F0F0'> <tr> <td align='center' valign='top' bgcolor='#F0F0F0' style='background-color: #F0F0F0;'> <br/> <table border='0' width='600' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='container'> <tr> <td class='he
```

I can't seem to track this down? Is the error in my function or the mail body? Is it an AWS limitation?

Thanks for your thoughts,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP servers can throw a "Line too long" error when a line of the email exceeds some server-defined length. Since your message is always truncated at the same spot try inserting line breaks into your message body. I know AWS SES SMTP can return this [error](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=173706) but I am unsure as to what the limit is. Here is a related [conversation](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20901430/CDO-Message-is-Truncated-on-Windows-2003-Server-Help.html) with a similar error and CDO for reference.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this!

Comment: Brilliant! I used the WordWrap function from this thread and applied to the HTML body. Works! http://forums.devarticles.com/asp-development-3/send-email-via-asp-15546.html

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks for the ASP/ADO blast from the past!

Answer (score 1):

CDO uses `7bit` for content transfer encoding by default, which does not truncate the long lines.

You don't need a user defined function but specify an appropriate content transfer encoding for the message body.

`8bit`, `quoted-printable` and `base64` are standard transfer encodings will take care of the long lines.

```
'...
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
myMail.HTMLBodyPart.ContentTransferEncoding = "8bit"
myMail.Send
'...
```